# Determining Android Screensize based on Resolution

Tags: android, screen-size

What are the criteria for a tablet device to fall under largescreens or xlargescreens?

I was looking at the Android dev guide and there is a clear definition for smallScreens and normalScreens, but the documentation is a bit vague regarding largescreens and xlargescreens.

> **smallScreens**
>   HVGA resolution
>
> **normalScreens**
>   HVGA with medium density
>   WQVGA with low density
>   WVGA with high density
>
> **largeScreens**
>   A large screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "normal" handset screen.
>
> **xlargeScreens**
>   An xlarge screen is defined as a screen that is significantly larger than a "large" screen.

Is there a resolution cut-off for largescreens? For example anything higher than or WSVGA (1024 × 600), and XGA (1024 × 768) is considered xlargeScreens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> smallScreens HVGA resolution

No.

> normalScreens HVGA with medium density WQVGA with low density WVGA with high density

Sorta.

> Is there a resolution cut-off for largescreens?

Resolution has nothing much to do with screen size. Screen size is self-explanatory: it is the size of the screen. I can have a 480x320 screen that is 1mm, 1cm, 1m, 1km, or 1 parsec in size.

Given resolution and density, you can compute a size, which is why your description of the `normal` screen size is close to correct.

The [Range of Screens Supported](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) section of the [Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) documentation shows the diagonal screen sizes buckets that Android supports and what physical sizes those tend to map to:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That was really helpful. I definitely missed this section of the dev guide.